# printing array values in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, code-translation

I'm trying to create a function that will run through an array and collect it's value to a string that looks like this: '[1,2,3]'. I also need it to present only part of the array in some cases, according to a given index. For example: the array [1,2,0] printed from index 0 to index 1 will look like this: '[1,2]'. For some reason my function don't give any output at all. Here it is:

```
function Tower(size, isFull) {
    this.count = 0;
    this.tower = new Array(size);

    this.add = function(disk) {
        this.tower[this.count++] = disk;
    };

    if (isFull) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            this.add(i);
        };
    }

    this.canAdd = function(disk) {
        return this.count == 0 || this.tower[this.count - 1] > disk;
    };

    this.getTopDiskValue = function() {
        return (this.count > 0) ? this.tower[this.count - 1] : 0;
    };

    this.popTop = function() {
        return this.tower[--this.count];
    };

    this.isFull = function() {
        return this.count == this.tower.length;
    };

    this.printable = function() {
        var output = "[";
        for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
            output += "" + this.tower[i] + ',';
        }
        return output.substring(0, output.length() - 1) + (output.length() > 1 ? ']' : "");
    };
}
```

I expect the printable() function to return the string so that the code:

```
var tower = new Tower(3,true);
alert(tower.printable());
```

will pop an alert box with the text '[1,2,3]' on it.
This object is a translation from Java. It worked great in java btw, I guess the translation is not perfect.

Comment: Check your error console and you will see the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is not Java - you don't get the length of an array or string by calling its `.length()` method, but just by retrieving its `.length` property. The exception which is thrown when you try to invoke the number is what crashes your script and prevents the alert. This would work:

```
this.printable = function() {
    var output = "[";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        output += "" + this.tower[i] + ',';
    }
    return output.substring(0, output.length - 1) + (output.length > 1 ? ']' : "");
};
```

However, you just can use the native [`.join()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to concatenate the array's values. Also, you should add your methods on the prototype of your `Tower` objects:

```
Tower.prototype.printable = function() {
    if (this.count)
        return "[" + this.tower.slice(0, this.count).join(",") + "]";
    else
        return "";
};
```

Btw: Usually this method is named `toString` - not only for convenience, but also it would get used when a Tower object is casted to a string value.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I usually call this method toString but tried to change it thinking it may cause the problem... XP
About adding the method to the prototype - isn't writing the method in the constructor equivalent to adding it to the prototype?

Comment: Check out [Use of 'prototype' vs. 'this' in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572) and the related answers I've linked in my comment there

Comment: So if I understand correctly, it boils down to wasting memory?

Comment: Yes, and that's bad practise. But the greater advantage is the *inheritance* from an object that can be dynamically changed - add/change a property on the prototype and *all* instances can use it

Answer (score 2):

What you do is much too complicated.

Let's say you have an array declared as

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
```

you get the desired string with

```
return '['+array.join(',')+']';
```

You don't need pop or add functions, they're also native (and heavily optimized) :

```
var last = array.pop()
array.push(newItem);
```

Reference :

- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)
- [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

Note that all browsers offer a console, in which you'll find a detailed explanation of your errors. Have a look for example at the [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/).

Comment: BTW about pop and push methods, I agree, but I was translating the code from Java and didn't want to start optimizing it at this point. The time will come to that :)

Answer (score 1):

use the `Array.join()` method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

---

```
this.printable = function() {
    var output = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < this.count; i++) {
        output.push(this.tower[i]);
    }
    return output.length == 0 
        ? "" 
        : "[" + output.join(",") + ']';
};
```

or if it's as simple as it looks:

```
this.printable = function() {
    return this.count == 0 
        ? "" 
        : "[" + this.tower.join(",") + ']';
};
```